# Why does dcc64 say this value is never used?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

The code below is from DDetours.pas. When it compiles for 32 bit, there are no warnings emitted. When it compiles for 64-bit, it emits this warning: (Delphi Berlin Update 2)

```
[dcc64 Hint] DDetours.pas(1019): H2077 Value assigned to 'Prf' never used
```

Here is the function in question

```
function GetPrefixesCount(Prefixes: WORD): Byte;

var
  Prf: WORD;
  i: Byte;
begin
  { Get prefixes count used by the instruction. }
  Result := 0;
  if Prefixes = 0 then
    Exit;

  Prf := 0;
  i := 0;
  Prefixes := Prefixes and not Prf_VEX;
  while Prf < $8000 do
  begin
    Prf := (1 shl i);
    if (Prf and Prefixes = Prf) then
      Inc(Result);
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

It sure looks to me like the very first time Prf is compared against $8000 that initial value is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a compiler bug. There are a few of this nature. Quite frustrating. Sometimes the 32 bit compiler will complain in an irrational manner and then when you workaround that the 64 bit compiler in turn complains in an irrational manner about your workaround.

I don't think that Embarcadero habitually compiler with hints and warnings enabled, because their library code is full of hints and warnings.

Anyway in this case the compiler sees the two writes to the variable but for some reason does not recognise the intervening read of the variable.

There's not a whole lot that you can do. You could submit a bug report. I expect that you don't want to change the code because it is third party code. If you don't change it then you'll have to put up with the bogus hint.

Notifying the author of the library might allow them to workaround the issue. Perhaps by suppressing hints for that function.

Comment: My solution is to add this to the top of the unit:

{$IFDEF WIN64}
{$HINTS OFF} // dcc64 gives invalid hints in this unit.
{$ENDIF}

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "I don't think that Embarcadero habitually compiler with hints and warnings enabled, because their library code is full of hints and warnings." Do you recompile the RTL/VCL/... or what makes you think so?

Comment: @StefanGlienke I recompile a handful of VCL units in order to workaround some defects. There are warnings and hints produced in all of them. Including a variable is declared but never used, and a whole bunch of symbol deprecated warnings. I'm still on XE7. Perhaps they've tightened up.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* the 64bit compiler has a small amount of smarts built-in to allow it to recognize that

- the variable is initialized and not touched again until the loop is entered.
- the loop condition is comparing the variable to a literal.
- the initial value of 0 satisfies the loop condition, thus ensuring the loop will always run at least once at runtime, effectively making it act like a `repeat..until` loop.

Since the compiler still has to generate code for the initialization, but knows the initial value is not needed at runtime to enter the loop, it can issue a warning that the initial value will be unused.

If you don't initialize the variable, the compiler doesn't know at compile-time whether the loop will be entered or not since the behavior is undefined, so the compiler issues a different warning about the variable being uninitialized.

---

Viewing the disassembly, you can see that the loop is turned into a `repeat..until` loop and the `Prf := 0;` assignment is removed by optimization:

```
Project87.dpr.17: Result := 0;
00000000004261AA 4833D2           xor rdx,rdx
Project87.dpr.18: if Prefixes = 0 then
00000000004261AD 6685C0           test ax,ax
00000000004261B0 7460             jz GetPrefixesCount + $72
Project87.dpr.22: i := 0;
00000000004261B2 4D33C0           xor r8,r8
Project87.dpr.23: Prefixes := Prefixes and not Prf_VEX;
00000000004261B5 0FB7C0           movzx eax,ax
00000000004261B8 81E02DFBFFFF     and eax,$fffffb2d
00000000004261BE 81F8FFFF0000     cmp eax,$0000ffff
00000000004261C4 7605             jbe GetPrefixesCount + $2B
00000000004261C6 E8050FFEFF       call @BoundErr
Project87.dpr.26: Prf := (1 shl i);
00000000004261CB 41C7C101000000   mov r9d,$00000001
00000000004261D2 418BC8           mov ecx,r8d
00000000004261D5 41D3E1           shl r9d,r9b
00000000004261D8 4489C9           mov ecx,r9d
00000000004261DB 81F9FFFF0000     cmp ecx,$0000ffff
00000000004261E1 7605             jbe GetPrefixesCount + $48
00000000004261E3 E8E80EFEFF       call @BoundErr
Project87.dpr.27: if (Prf and Prefixes = Prf) then
00000000004261E8 448BC9           mov r9d,ecx
00000000004261EB 664423C8         and r9w,ax
00000000004261EF 66443BC9         cmp r9w,cx
00000000004261F3 750A             jnz GetPrefixesCount + $5F
Project87.dpr.28: Inc(Result);
00000000004261F5 80C201           add dl,$01
00000000004261F8 7305             jnb GetPrefixesCount + $5F
00000000004261FA E8F10EFEFF       call @IntOver
Project87.dpr.29: Inc(i);
00000000004261FF 4180C001         add r8b,$01
0000000000426203 7305             jnb GetPrefixesCount + $6A
0000000000426205 E8E60EFEFF       call @IntOver
Project87.dpr.24: while Prf < $8000 do
000000000042620A 6681F90080       cmp cx,$8000
000000000042620F 72BA             jb GetPrefixesCount + $2B
```

Comment: I don't think so, because if you change the initialization to $8000, which means the loop will never be entered, the hint goes away.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs: Same thing. In that case, the compiler can know at compile time that the loop would never be entered at runtime since the first evaluation would always be false, but it still has to generate code for the initialization of the variable, and so it can warn knowing that assignment is going to be unused.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: unless you are on the compiler team, you don't know what it actually does. I'm speculating, so are you. But I don't see it being difficult for it to perform certain simple flow analysis like this when it is compiling the loop evaluation code.

Comment: Regardless, in this case, a repeat..until loop is more appropriate.

Comment: This doesn't ring true. If you don't initialize the variable then the behaviour becomes undefined. The initialization is needed at runtime.

Comment: As far as data flow analysis goes, it always used to be the case, so far as I knew, that the compiler did none. However, if the value that the variable is initialized to matters then that can't be the case any more. Still, it's a clear defect all the same.

Comment: Seems to me like the compiler is clever enough to convert to repeat until but then too stupid to remove the initialization. That would explain everything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, the initialization is removed, but the hint remains.

Comment: I too think the issue is "optimization" fighting with the flow analysis, but find the way the loop is written perplexing.  The loop simply runs for 16 iterations deriving `Prf` to test each bit of `prefixes` in turn.  Rather than a **while** or a **repeat** the loop could be more simply implemented as a **for** loop with `prf` a const array with values for each iteration rather than bit shifting.  Also, I don't get any hints from either 32 or 64-bit compilers for the OP's code in XE4, suggesting that something has changed, whether that be in the code analysis or the optimization affecting it.

Comment: The code you added gives a very clear steer that your reasoning was right, but the answer still reads as though you believe that the compiler is right to emit this hint. It's pretty clearly a compiler bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: just to be clear, I did not add the code, LU RD did.

Comment: If the compiler uses the initial value to determine that a repeat until is more optimal and makes the optimization, it should not emit a warning suggesting that the initial value is not needed, because logically it is. Bottom line: it is a bug for the compiler to emit this hint.

Answer (score 1):

well, I guess the answer is that dcc64 is a buggy compiler when it comes to messages. Because if you comment out the offending line, "value never used" becomes "might not have been initialized." Same compiler.

```
[dcc64 Warning] DDetours.pas(1022): W1036 Variable 'Prf' might not have been initialized
```

Comment: It's not so much that dcc64 is defective. There are plenty of similar problems with dcc32 also.